# vb.net Select Case error

Tags: vb.net

When i want define values in `Select Case` i got error:

```
'Value' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

When `Dim Value As Object` is outside Select Case - No error. My target is get Value different on special numbers.  For example:

```
Select Case Integer
     Case 1
         Dim Value As New UserControl1
     Case 2
         Dim Value As New UserControl2
     Case Else
         Dim Value As New UserControl3
End Select
```

Comment: look up the vb scoping rules.  variables declared within a select block would be scoped to the select block.

Comment: I wouldn't name a variable `Value`, particularly as it is an Object; very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, assuming all 3 user control types derive from the base `UserControl` object:

```
Dim Value as UserControl
Select Case Integer
     Case 1
         Value = New UserControl1
     Case 2
         Value = New UserControl2
     Case Else
         Value = New UserControl3
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not passable to declare a variable inside a scope and access it outside the scope such as as select case statement. However you problem is easily solved by separating the declaration and initialization. This enables you to use the variable outside the select case as the variable is in the higher scope. The variable is declared as System.Windows.Controls.UserControl as this is the most specific common type.

```
Dim Value As UserControl
Select Case Integer
     Case 1
         Value = New UserControl1
     Case 2
         Value = New UserControl2
     Case Else
         Value = New UserControl3
End Select
```